# Java OpenGL version selecton procedure

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am a bit confused as to what OpenGL version I should tell LWJGL that I am using. I have a GPU that supports 4.4 and am coding for that, however I also want to test it occasionally on an older PC that has a GPU supporting 3.3.

Actually I am confused about almost everything in OpenGL versioning, this is the code I use now:

```
abstract public class Controller {
    //...
    private final List<Context> contextList = new ArrayList<>();
    //...

    private void initConstructor() {
        if (debug) {
            this.debugger = new Debugger();
            this.debuggerThread = new Thread(this.debugger);
            this.debuggerThread.start();
        }

        contextList.add(new Context(4, 4, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(4, 3, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(4, 2, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(4, 1, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(4, 0, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(3, 3, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(3, 2, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(3, 1, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(3, 0, true, true));
        contextList.add(new Context(2, 1, false, false));
        contextList.add(new Context(2, 0, false, false));
    }

    public void start() {
        LWJGLException exception = null;
        Context currentContext = contextList.get(0);
        try {
            for (Context context : contextList) {
                DisplayMode[] displayModes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
                DisplayMode chosenDisplayMode = null;
                DisplayMode desktopDisplayMode = Display.getDesktopDisplayMode();
                for (DisplayMode displayMode : displayModes) {
                    if (desktopDisplayMode.getWidth() == displayMode.getWidth() && 
                            desktopDisplayMode.getHeight() == displayMode.getHeight() && 
                            desktopDisplayMode.getBitsPerPixel() == displayMode.getBitsPerPixel() && 
                            desktopDisplayMode.getFrequency() == displayMode.getFrequency()) {
                        chosenDisplayMode = displayMode;
                    }
                }
                if (chosenDisplayMode == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("No display mode has been found for desktop display mode: " + desktopDisplayMode);
                }
                screenWidth = chosenDisplayMode.getWidth();
                screenHeight = chosenDisplayMode.getHeight();
                System.out.println("Chosen display mode: " + chosenDisplayMode);
                Display.setDisplayMode(chosenDisplayMode);
                Display.setFullscreen(true);
                Display.setResizable(false);
                Display.setTitle("3D Game");
                Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
                ContextAttribs contextAttribs = new ContextAttribs(context.major, context.minor);
                if (context.useForwardCompatible) {
                    contextAttribs = contextAttribs.withForwardCompatible(context.useForwardCompatible);
                }
                if (context.useProfileCore) {
                    contextAttribs = contextAttribs.withProfileCore(context.useProfileCore);
                }
                Display.create(new PixelFormat(), contextAttribs);
                exception = null;
                break;
            }
        } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
            exception = ex;
        }

        if (exception != null) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
            System.err.println("Display wasn't initialized correctly.");
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Started OpenGL with the following parameters:");
        System.out.println("Major version: " + currentContext.major);
        System.out.println("Minor version: " + currentContext.minor);
        System.out.println("Forward compatible: " + currentContext.useForwardCompatible);
        System.out.println("Profile Core: " + currentContext.useProfileCore);

        try {
            init();
            initSuccesful = true;

            while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
                renderChecks();
                renderImpl();
                inputChecks();
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            shutdownImpl();
        }
    }

    //...

    private class Context {
        private final int major;
        private final int minor;
        private final boolean useForwardCompatible;
        private final boolean useProfileCore;

        Context(final int major, final int minor, final boolean useForwardCompatible, final boolean useProfileCore) {
            this.major = major;
            this.minor = minor;
            this.useForwardCompatible = useForwardCompatible;
            this.useProfileCore = useProfileCore;
        }
    }
```

It results in the (rather simple) program working on my older PC aswell, however sadly it includes flashing the screen like 5 times when it is trying to create a display each time on the older PC.

Another strange thing (more or less a bonus question), is that currently when I start it on my PC it involves flashing the screen once very shortly (flashing with a black screen), then normal and then it switches to fullscreen.

Comment: Also, core is undefined for 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I do not plan on supporting those obsolete versions, though you may wonder why I support 2.x aswell, and honestly that is the part that I do not know. Would supporting 4.4 and 3.3 be enough already? If possible without flashing the screen.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I need a working one. If 4.4 doesn't work (`LWJGLException` then it falls back to the lower one, etc. I cannot get the version with a `gl*` method withotu being in a context. If I could know the OpenGL version upfront, then that would be great.

Comment: Just request a context with the actual feature set you need. I sincerely doubt you use any of the features from OpenGL 4.4. 3.2 is probably the most compatible baseline version to target. 3.3 was just recently added to OS X, so it is also gaining traction.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I plan on using the Tessellation and possibly Geometry shaders though, if I recall correctly atleast one of them got added in 4.0? But I've also heard that 3.3 is compatible with 4.0? Would requesting a 3.3 context then work?

Comment: Geometry Shaders are core in 3.2. Tessellation requires 4.0. But there is no reason to do this the way you are right now. You will know if you are trying to use tessellation shaders, so you can request a 4.0 context then. There is no reason to create 11 contexts. Besides, it is not like the context version restricts you from using newer features if the driver supports them. If you get a 3.2 context on 4.4 hardware, you can still use the 4.4 extensions. The only thing requesting a certain context version does for you is make context creation fail if the version is not supported.

Comment: Geometry came in 3.2, Tessellation was 4.0. Surely the best approach is to let LWJGL choose the best-fit Context and query it later to see what you can support rather than forcing it? Getting the application to throw Exceptions until you hit one that works is bad practice. At the very least LWJGL does have someway to ask for the Highest GL Version supported, authough I cannot remember where it is...

Comment: @MichaelDuller I've searched quite long to find that on LWJGL but was unable to find it, and I agree that all the context creation is bad hence why I came here. I think that it is best to go with the 4.0 context (because honestly if it ever gets commercial/publicly, we are 2+ years ahead).